# Regex for Should consist of 8 to 20 numeric characters including spaces and one hyphen, and hyphen cannot be the first or the last character

Tags: javascript

I was trying to write regex for above mentioned rule I tried this way but its not working

```
"(?=^([0-9]|-){8,20}$)^[0-9]+[/-/][0-9]+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

so, you could make the problem much simpler by creating a regex that tests that a string consists of 8 to 20 characters (numeric, space or hyphen), where the hyphen cannot be the first or the last character:

```
/^[\d\s][\d\s\-]{6,18}[\d\s]$/
```

and then test that the string contains a single hypen:

```
/^[^\-]*\-[^\-]*$/
```

and then that it contains a space:

```
/\s/
```

I appreciate this is a slightly different answer than what you were asking for, but thought it might help

Comment: Thanks clarke : problem is that i have to make array of regex which i will test with common logic so i cannot write specific logic to test single hyphen ,everything i have to give in regex itself

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to check the length AND the format of the string with only one regex. However, you could achieve this with 2 steps, for example:

```
var formatRegex = /^\d+(?:\d|\s)*-(?:\d|\s)+$/;
var myText = '111-111 11 111';
if (formatRegex.test(myText)) {
  if (myText.length >= 8 && myText.length <= 20) {
    console.log('ok');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9](?:([0-9]{5,17}-)|(?=[0-9]*[-][0-9]*$)[0-9-]{6,18})[0-9]$
```

this regex is working
explanation:
it will check string starting with [0-9] and ending with [0-9]
now for remaining string of length we can have this pattern (?:[0-9]{5,17}|(?=[0-9]*[-][0-9]*$)[0-9-]{6,18})
where  ?:([0-9]{5,17}-) will check presence of 5 to 17 numbers and one - in string 
demo:
https://regex101.com/r/eO3jK8/1